# Convert drawOval circle into x,y coordinates

Tags: java, arrays, drawing, store, geometry

I want to convert the drawn circle into x,y coordinates and store in an array or string. I have to use this array to store an image file from my frame.

```
private final DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();

    private static int[] generateRandomValues(int maxX, int maxY, 
                                       int minSize, int maxSize) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] values = new int[3];
        values[0] = random.nextInt(maxX);
        values[1] = random.nextInt(maxY);
        values[2] = Math.min(random.nextInt(maxSize) + minSize, maxSize);
        return values;
    }

    static class Circle {

        int x, y, width, height;

        public Circle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    static class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Circle circle : circles) {
                circle.draw(g);
            }
        }

        public void addCircle(Circle circle) {
            circles.add(circle);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }
```

in my main function i have written the following code:

```
DrawingPanel drawPane = new DrawingPanel();
int[] circleValues = generateRandomValues(300, 300, 50, 150);
                int x = circleValues[0];
                int y = circleValues[1];
                int width = circleValues[2];
                int height = width;
                Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, width, height);
                drawPane.addCircle(circle);
```

Comment: how do you detect what was drawn?

Comment: please see my edited question.

Comment: not sure what you mean.  can you not just list.add(circleValues)?

Comment: `I want to convert the drawn circle into x,y coordinates`  - what do you mean? You have the x/y coordinates in your circle class. You really need to learn how to ask a question that we can understand.

Comment: it will only give me the x and y coordinate of the circle center but not the whole circle. I want the circle to be represented as a set of small lines with a list of x, y coordinates, like a circle of radius (1,1,5,5) "1" list =[(x,y coordinates), (etc.), (etc.), (5,5)] which lies on the circle.

Comment: `I want the circle to be represented as a set of small lines with a list of x, y coordinates.` why would you do that instead of storing the x/y/width/height?

Comment: I have a requirement in my code to do this. I have to store the array in image format later.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to store the array in image format later

what does that mean? An Array of points is not an image.

If you want to know what is painted on the screen, then you can:

1. create a BufferedImage of your panel. See [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) for an easy way to do this.
2. Then you can iterate through the BufferedImage one pixel at a time. If the Color of the pixel is not equal to the color of the background of the panel, then that means you painted something there. So you save the x/y value of that pixel in your ArrayList.